# How to Create Script for Update database Automaticly IN SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Database On SQL Server 2008 , and I want Update All records in this database from anther database ON db2 . I want to do Script work Daily ON time Or when I Want Update, do that manual from this script .

How can I do that?

Comment: why not use SSIS? it will allow you to perform all your neccessary data transforms and clean ups before hitting the SQL DB.

Comment: I Dont Know How I Make It By SSIS Or Any Other Way . Please help me , What should I do ?

Comment: Hire someone who knows how, I guess?

Comment: RaJ , I Can't Hire Person , it's My Work , But I Want Get The Beginning of the Way then Iam Sure that I'll Do It , I want Someone Help Me to do that , Not to Make That !!

Comment: Ohh....................Ok I Suggest Way To How To Do That

Answer (score 1):

There Are Two Way To Automaticaly Update Your Database

1) Create DTS For Update Your database one to other

2) Care Consol Application To Upadat One To Other

[DTS](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1034165-using-dts-copy-one-database-into-another-how-long-should-take-1-5-gigs.html)